# Stuck with this query

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

My database looks like this

**DailyData**

```
rID int
Stock varchar
rDate date
Shares int
price float
```

What I am trying to do is get the data for two dates.

**Sample data**

```
rID    stock    rDate        Shares    price
11     Stock1   21/03/2016   15        1.22
12     Stock2   21/03/2016   22        2.23
13     Stock3   21/03/2016   17        3.32
14     Stock4   21/03/2016   10        4.24
15     Stock1   22/03/2016   15        1.25
16     Stock2   22/03/2016   20        2.27
17     Stock3   22/03/2016   17        3.32
18     Stock1   23/03/2016   15        1.28
19     Stock2   23/03/2016   20        2.20
20     Stock3   23/03/2016   17        3.32
21     Stock4   23/03/2016   10        4.24
```

**Expected output**

```
Stock       Shares-21    Shares-20
Stock1      15           15
Stock2      22           20
Stock3      17           17
Stock4      10           0
```

My query against a SQL Server CE database:

```
Select 
    DD1.Stock, sum(DD1.Shares) as Shares-21, sum(DD2.shares) as Shares-20
from 
    DailyData DD1, DailyData DD2
where 
    DD1.rDate = '21/03/2016' and DD2.rDate = '20/03/2016' 
    and DD1.Stock = DD2.Stock
group by 
    DD1.Stock
```

I am getting 7 rows of data instead of 4.

Please help with the query.

*******************************  new modification *********************
i followed as suggested but it seems not to work.  this is a actual sql script.

```
Select P.pName,DD.Stock, 
  sum(case DD.rDate when '03/21/2016' then DD.Shares  else 0 end) as Shares21, 
  sum(case DD.rDate when '03/20/2016' then DD.Shares else  0 end) as Shares20
from dailyData DD, Portfolios P
where DD.rDate = '03/21/2016' or DD.rDate = '03/20/2016'
  and DD.pID = P.pID
  and DD.pID=1
group by P.pName,DD.stock
order by P.pName,DD.Stock
```

now for pID=1 there are 23 records for 20-Mar and 21-Mar

upon running this query, it returns way more than 23.  I am expecting 23 records only.

Comment: To include dashes in an identifier, it has to be delimited. E.g `"Shares-21"`.

Comment: yes that's a typo, pls ignore

Comment: Why don't you correct it instead?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Comment: oh i had a nightmare correcting the monospaces ....  just gave up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually does not need to use JOIN. You could use CASE WHEN statement like this

```
SELECT stock, 
       Sum(CASE rdate 
             WHEN '21/03/2016' THEN shares 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS Shares21, 
       Sum(CASE rdate 
             WHEN '20/03/2016' THEN shares 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS Shares20 
FROM   dailydata 
WHERE  rdate = '21/03/2016' 
        OR rdate = '20/03/2016' 
GROUP  BY stock
```

Comment: there seems to be some problem with the code, am getting way too many records than expected.  am expecting 23 records.  pls see my actual script added just now.  Thanks

Comment: You should update your WHERE condition to (DD.rDate = '03/21/2016' or DD.rDate = '03/20/2016')
  and DD.pID = P.pID and DD.pID=1

Comment: that is exactly what i have done ....   and i get more than 23 records.

Comment: oh you meant, just to add the brackets (  )   yes done that ... works like a charm.  thanks !!!

Comment: i am getting a few stocks with 0 shares for both the dates.  is there a way to avoid that.  if either of the dates have anything other than zero then its alright, but otherwise can i skip such rows?

Comment: You could try to add HAVING statement at the end of your query ...GROUP  BY stock HAVING Shares20 <> 0 OR Shares21 <> 0

Comment: i tried to modify this query for another scenario and its not working need help.  I have a field called pID, which is portfolio ID.  i want a count of how many records are there for each of the portfolios for each of the dates.  So basically the above query i replaced Stock with pID and replaced sum with count, and grouped by pID.  for both the dates am getting the same data, i.e. 96, while actual record count for lets say pID=1 is only 22 records.

Comment: To archive result that you want, you could try to update *CASE WHEN* statement like this: *COUNT(CASE rdate WHEN '21/03/2016' THEN 1 END) AS Count21*. You could also use SUM function, for example: *SUM(CASE rdate WHEN '21/03/2016' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count21*

Comment: i did this for 4 dates, and for pID=1 i get result as 308, 322, 322, 322  and for pID=2 i get the result as 308, 322, 322, 322  same for pID 3 and so on.  Not exactly what i had in mind.

Comment: c# ??  no idea how to go about.

Comment: You could change from C# to Sql Server

Comment: Super .... works like a charm .....  i guess the cast was messing up on my side.  many thanks @Trung

Answer (score 0):

You could use PIVOT with DATEPART

```
      SELECT Stock, [21] AS [Shares-21], [20] AS [Shares-20] FROM
      (
         SELECT s.Stock, Datepart(d,s.rDate) rDate , s.Shares FROM DailyData s
      ) src
      PIVOT
      (
         MAX(Shares) for rDate in ([21], [20])
      ) pvt
```